# How come when I overide the __div__ method in a class, it dowsn't work when I am testing the code?

Tags: python, class, math, operators

I want to write a fraction class that allows arithmetic operators, but when I defined the **div** method it doesn't seem to be able to divide though.

```
from math import gcd

class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, n, d):
        self.n = n
        self.d = d
    def __add__(self, other):
        newn = self.n * other.d + self.d * other.n
        newd = self.d * other.d
        common = gcd(newn, newd)
        return Fraction(newn/common, newd/common)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        newn = self.n * other.d - self.d * other.n
        newd = self.d * other.d
        common = gcd(newn, newd)
        return Fraction(newn/common, newd/common)
    def __div__(self, other):
        newn = self.n * other.d
        newd = self.d * other.n
        common = gcd(newn, newd)
        return Fraction(newn/common, newd/common)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        newn = self.n * other.n
        newd = self.d * other.d
        common = gcd(newn, newd)
        return Fraction(newn/common, newd/common)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(int(self.n), int(self.d))

print(Fraction(1, 2) / Fraction(1, 4))
```

Comment: You are using Python 3, which uses `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__` for `/` and `//` respectively. https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__truediv__ https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__floordiv__

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `__truediv__` in Python 3